# Using [out] SAFEARRAY(byte) in ATL/COM

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, com, atl

In Visual Sturdio 2008 I've created a simple Visual C++ ATL Project in which I have a simple class `MyTestCOMClass`. I'm using the VS's *Add Method Wizard* for creating methods of this class, let's call them `methodA` and `methodB`.

`methodA` has one input parameter of the type `SAFEARRAY`, it's defined as below:

```
[id(1), helpstring("method methodA")] HRESULT methodA([in] SAFEARRAY(byte) inputA);
```

If I try to compile the project it compiles fine.

If I however add also `methodB` defined like this:

```
[id(2), helpstring("method methodB")] HRESULT methodB([in] SAFEARRAY(byte) inputB, [out] SAFEARRAY(byte) outputB);
```

when compiling I obtain the error:

`.\MyTestCOMClass.idl(23) : error MIDL2121 : [out] only parameter must not derive from a top-level [unique] or [ptr] pointer/array : [ Type 'wirePSAFEARRAY' ( Parameter 'outputB' ) ]`

I understand that the problem is with using `[out] SAFEARRAY(byte)` type in `methodB` but I don't understand why. I'm new to ATL/COM so could somebody explain to me this problem?

Comment: `[out]` requires that parameter is a pointer, that is a "by reference" thing. E.g. `SAFEARRAY*`, not `SAFEARRAY`.

Comment: The thing is the _Add Method Wizzard_ in VS2008 doesn't create `SAFEARRAY*` even if I specify it in _Parameter type:_ column of the wizard - it strips the pointer and creates only the `SAFEARRAY` type parameter.

Comment: Visual Studio is equipped with a text editor, and your computer with a keyboard. If the wizard wouldn't generate the correct code, then you the  programmer get to fix it. The parameter should be declared as `[out] SAFEARRAY(byte)*`  in IDL, which translates to `SAFEARRAY**` in C++.

Comment: Unfortunately the comment of @Hans Passant has disappeared in this thread, but it seems like a bug in VS2008's wizard - he can't handle `SAFEARRAY(byte)*` as parameter type and strips away the pointer, so in the IDL he creates only `SAFEARRAY(byte)` type which causes the error I get. The thing is, I don't know what else (besides creating the definition in the IDL) does the wizard do and modifying only the IDL to the desired definition causes several compilation errors from inside the VS's code so that is likely not the best way to go.